# why java AbstractQueuedSynchronizer next link is not atomically set as part of insertion

Tags: concurrency, java.util.concurrent

As Doug Lea point in the [The java.util.concurrent Synchronizer Framework
][1]http://gee.cs.oswego.edu/dl/papers/aqs.pdf that

> But because there are no applicable techniques for lock-free atomic insertion of  double-linked list nodes using compareAndSet, this link is not atomically set as part of insertion; it is simply assigned.
>
> pred.next = node;
>
> after the insertion. This is reflected in all usages. The next link is treated only as an optimized path. If a node's successor does not appear to exist (or 
>    appears to be cancelled) via its next field, it is always possible to start at the tail of the list and traverse backwards using the pred field to accurately 
>    check if there really is one.

the add node to sync queue code snippet is, copied form AbstractQueuedSynchronizer source code :

```
private Node enq(final Node node) {
    for (;;) {
        Node t = tail;
        if (t == null) { // Must initialize
            if (compareAndSetHead(new Node()))
                tail = head;
        } else {
            node.prev = t;
            if (compareAndSetTail(t, node)) {
                t.next = node;
                return t;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

my question is, in the sourcecode, the **next** field of a **Node** class is a volatile object, if **compareAndSetTail** success, then the next field of t must not be null, why there may be a **null** situation. the code snippet is:

```
static final class Node {
 //....ignored
     volatile Node next;
     volatile Node prev;
 //.... ignored
}
```

Also, I don't quite understand **hasQueuedPredecessors**. If h != t, then h's next filed should not be null, why **h.next == null** also means hasQueuedPredecessors?

```
public final boolean hasQueuedPredecessors() {
    // The correctness of this depends on head being initialized
    // before tail and on head.next being accurate if the current
    // thread is first in queue.
    Node t = tail; // Read fields in reverse initialization order
    Node h = head;
    Node s;
    return h != t &&
        ((s = h.next) == null || s.thread != Thread.currentThread());
}
```

Comment: I know Node is a volatile reference, but it's next field is also volatile, so I don't understand, if a node's next field is changed, why other thread cannot see it, volatile should guarantee the next field visibility

Comment: You seem to have a very naive view on threads, assuming that there are only two threads at most and both threads conveniently stopping at certain points to ensure that the other thread completed its work. That’s not how `volatile` variables work. When a thread updates two variables (non-atomically), there is always an “in-between” and another thread may read these two variables right at this point. Or even try to update them at this point, in an attempt to insert another node. And now imagine three threads trying to enqueue a new node and another five trying to dequeue a node at the same time…

Comment: Holger, thanks for answering. you mean that use the code above, in one thread **A**, `compareAndSetTail(t, node)` has finished, then other thread **B** can "see" the change of tail, because this is a atomic update, but `t.next = node` may can't be visibility to it for there is no _happen before_ relationship between `t.next = node` and **B** "see" the change.

Comment: I think, you got it. B might step in after A’s `compareAndSetTail(t, node)` when the subsequent `t.next = node` has not even been executed, letting visibility aside. Since these are two distinct actions, an arbitrary time may elapse between them, even if they are next to each other in program code. E.g. A may lose the CPU right after the first action and a lot of threads may run in the meanwhile, not only observing this incomplete state, but even altering it by inserting more nodes or removing some. And each of these updates may overlap with others as well.

Comment: Holger, thank you, this question really bothered me this week.